# How to get a channel chat message from twitch

Tags: java

Im wondering how I can get the latest chat message from a Twitch Chat channel without need to use OAuth. I woud love to get also the color of the user that is sending the message.

Also I did some search on Google cause and all I found was via IRC and didnt understand it that much so can any1 help me out how to get the latest chat message or just the whole chat.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Look for a twitch api? [Found this in 5 seconds.](https://github.com/justintv/twitch-api)

Comment: You have to connect to twitch chat using IRC, which you cannot do without using OAuth.

Comment: Oke thanks guys, sorry for my way of asking but I will read that thing. Also thanks for the info Didnt google for API :$ What I normally do first